# Simple Bash script: What is wrong?

Tags: bash

I use Ubuntu Server as you can see:

```
#uname -a
Linux grosella 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Supose a data file like this (/tmp/data.txt):

```
1 AAAA
2 BBBB
3 CCCC
4 DDDD
5 EEEE
6 FFFF
```

Run the following Bash script:

```
typeset -i ACUM=0
typeset -a V=('')

cat /tmp/data.txt | \
while read LINEA ; do
  [ "x$LINEA" == "x" ] && break
  V=( $LINEA )
  VAL="${V[0]}"
  [ "x$VAL" == "x" ] && continue
  [[ $VAL =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || continue
  ((ACUM+=VAL))
  echo -e "VAL=$VAL\t\tACUM=$ACUM"
done

echo -e "\nFinal Result: $ACUM"
```

And here is the printed output:

```
VAL=1       ACUM=1
VAL=2       ACUM=3
VAL=3       ACUM=6
VAL=4       ACUM=10
VAL=5       ACUM=15
VAL=6       ACUM=21

Final Result: 0
```

Instead of 21, final result is 0. What is wrong?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Boo/hiss for not coming up with a better description of your problem before asking it. (See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code from

```
cat /tmp/data.txt | \
while read LINEA ; do
  # ...
done
```

to

```
while read LINEA ; do
  # ...
done < /tmp/data.txt
```

to avoid two subshells with its own environment.

Comment: I did it  ... For me, problem solved!!

Answer (score 3):

When you pipe the data to your while loop that creates a subshell in which the while loop runs.  The subshell cannot alter the environment variables of the parent, so the outer `ACUM` does not get changed.

Comment: That's rigth! ... Thanks